# How to loop through array/object in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have an object through which i want to loop. Currently am looping it as below :

```
for(var i = 0; i< coupons.length; i++) {
   var couponObj = [];
var coupon=coupons[i];

var casper = require('casper').create();            
casper.start();




     casper.then(function(){console.log(JSON.stringify(coupon);}
    //some other work
    );

}
```

Issue with this is its executing the loop at once without entering the `casper.then(function(){console.log('here')}`

Once it executed the loop then it executes  `casper.then(function(){console.log(JSON.stringify(coupon);}` with the last value ie. `coupons[coupons.length]`

Answer (score 1):

Because many of CasperJS' functions are asynchronous, not wrapping your code in a `Casper.then` will cause them to run out of order. You can fix that with the following.

```
var coupons = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]; // fake values for testing

casper.start();

casper.then(function() {
    this.eachThen(coupons, function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    });
});

casper.run();
```

This requires at least CasperJS [1.1-beta1](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#eachthen) to run.

Comment: basically i want to launch multiple casper instances per coupon element. The current solution will launch only 1 casper instance and then work with the coupon object

Comment: As far as I know, you can only have 1 casper instance per script.

Comment: I tried launching multiple casperJS instance with the mentioned code in question. It is creating the multiple instances but with the issue which i mentioned.